# How to Configure Axios Proxy Settings for Windows URL?

Tags: javascript, windows, axios, proxy

I have a URL that requires enabling a proxy in the Windows settings (as shown in the picture), and it works.

The way I invoke this URL is as follows:

```
const response = await axios.get('https://example.com/api/foo');
```

I'd like to configure the proxy in `axios` so I can remove the proxy settings from Windows, but I tried the following examples and they didn't work (I received a 404 error):

```
const response = await axios.get('https://example.com/api/foo', { proxy: { host: '192.168.204.81', port: 8080 } });

const response = await axios.get('https://example.com/api/foo', { proxy: { host: 'http://192.168.204.81', port: 8080 } });

const response = await axios.get('https://example.com/api/foo', { proxy: { host: 'https://192.168.204.81', port: 8080 } });

const response = await axios.get('https://example.com/api/foo', { proxy: { host: '192.168.204.81', port: 8080 }, httpsAgent: new Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: false }) });
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to configure it correctly to make it work?

[image]

Comment: according to what passes as documentation, the example is `protocol: 'https', host: '127.0.0.1', port: 9000, auth: { username: 'mikeymike', password: 'rapunz3l'}` - the `protocol` defaults to `https`,  and `auth` is optional - so, your first attempt looks correct, unless the protocol needs to be `https` of course